# Play JPA - Error: Removing a detached instance

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, persistence

I'm using Play Framework 2.4 and
I got this error:

```
[IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance models.Account#8]
 In: (...)\models\Account.java
    JPA.em().remove(this)
```

My code looks like this:

- *ProfileController*: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=257PThm4
- *Account*: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=WN1WChni

---

I also tried (as suggested by many other answers to similar questions):

```
JPA.em.remove(JPA.em().merge(this);
```

or

```
JPA.em().remove(Account.findById(this.id));
```

or adding `@Transactional` to the delete() function.

But they both result in

> RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

.

### UPDATE - My solution:

It was a mixture of two problems:

1. I missed a line in the console output saying there was a constraint from another table and that the Account cannot be deleted.
2. The account instance returned by `Component.currentAccount()` was a detached instance and I fixed that with:

   `Account current = JPA.em().merge(Component.currentAccount())`

Answer (score 1):

Only a guess: The object tree must be in sync with the database structure.

If you remove a JPA controlled bean, you must remove it also from collections, where it possibly is also a part of.

So, if the account is part of a list of accounts in a company or is listed in a AccessGroup, then you must remove it from those elements before the account can be deleted. This is only valid if those other objects are currently loaded into your JPA session.

The initial error you have posted should have been resolved by explicitely reloading the object or reconnecting the object with the persistent state as has been proposed by others.

If my guess is right, and you use hibernate, the commit failure is accompanied by something like `deleted object would be re-saved by cascade`.